# Change Material of a Sphere on Focus for VR 360 Degree Image App in Unity3d

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I am creating an app for google-cardboard, App like 360 degree image.
I created a sphere and I made 62 material with different 360 degree image.
I created 2 button, next and previous, when i focus on next button its changing to next material as i want. but when i focus on previous button, its changing to last material which i dont want. What I want is just previous material.

Here is my code. See and tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class next : MonoBehaviour {

    public CardboardHead head;
    public Material[] myMaterials = new Material[60];
    int maxMaterials;
    int arrayPos = 0;
    public GameObject Sphere;
    public int timeToCompleteLoading = 3;
    bool wait = false;

    void Start ()
    {
        head = Camera.main.GetComponent<StereoController> ().Head;
        maxMaterials = myMaterials.Length-1;

    }

    public void ToggleVRMode() 
    {
        Cardboard.SDK.VRModeEnabled = !Cardboard.SDK.VRModeEnabled;
    }

    IEnumerator RadialProgress(float time)
    {
        wait = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);

        float rate = 1 / time;
        float i = 0;
        while (i < 1)
        {
            i += Time.deltaTime * rate;
            gameObject.renderer.material.SetFloat("_Progress", i);

        }
        wait = false;
    }

    void updateMaterials(){
        if (collider.gameObject.tag == "next") {
            if (arrayPos == maxMaterials){
                arrayPos = 0;
            }else{

                arrayPos++;
                Sphere.renderer.material = myMaterials [arrayPos];
            }
        }
         if (collider.gameObject.tag == "previous") {
            if (arrayPos == 0){
                arrayPos = maxMaterials;
            }else{
                arrayPos--;
                Sphere.renderer.material = myMaterials [arrayPos];

            }
        }


    }


    void Update ()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Collider collider = GetComponent<Collider> ();

        if (collider) {

            bool isLookAt = collider.Raycast (head.Gaze, out hit, Mathf.Infinity);
            if (isLookAt == true) {
                if(wait == false){
                    StartCoroutine (RadialProgress (timeToCompleteLoading));

                    updateMaterials();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On first run, it will jump to the last but if you first look at next and then at previous it should get to previous one. But do you mean that when you look at next and then at previous it jumps to last?

Comment: On a different issue,  the code in the while of the coroutine won't do what you expect. You need to yield return null from the while loop so that it returns control to the program. In this situation, it will do the whole movement in one frame.

Comment: On first run, when i focus on previous its changing to last[61] as it should. because initial position is [0], but when i focus on next its jumping to [1]. it should jump to [0], but on first run when i focus on next its working fine. like [0], [1], [2]...... so on after when i focus on previous is jumping to [60]. @fafase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something wrong in what you describe. There is 60 materials, so maxMaterial should be 59 (0 to 59 is 60 spots). But you say it shows 61 and 60 and that should be out of bounds. Also, since maxMaterial is 59 (60 -1), when your index is 60 or 61, your if statement does not do.

You could review like so:

```
 void updateMaterials(){
    if (collider.gameObject.tag == "next") {
        if (++arrayPos == myMaterials.Length){
            arrayPos = 0;
        }
    }
    else if (collider.gameObject.tag == "previous") {
        if (--arrayPos < 0){
            arrayPos = myMaterials.Length - 1;
        }
    }
    Sphere.renderer.material = myMaterials [arrayPos];
}
```

P.S.: As I mentioned in a comment, your while loop in the coroutine will not do any delayed process:

```
    while (i < 1)
    {
        i += Time.deltaTime * rate;
        gameObject.renderer.material.SetFloat("_Progress", i);
    }
```

The while loop runs within a single frame.

```
    while (i < 1)
    {
        i += Time.deltaTime * rate;
        gameObject.renderer.material.SetFloat("_Progress", i);
        yield return null;
    }
```

Now the while loop runs over several frames.

Comment: Sorry, I changed to 61 in inspector panel @fafase

Comment: Sir, I got confused... can u write full code. now i understand. @fafase

Comment: That is the full code I guess, first is the UpdatePanel method, second part replaces the while loop in the coroutine (not related to origin question).

Comment: Its giving error in  arrayPos = maxMaterials.Length - 1; Assets/Scripts/next.cs(50,57): error CS1061: Type `int' does not contain a definition for `Length' and no extension method `Length' of type `int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) @fafase

Comment: My mistake, typos. It should be the length of the array. I fixed the answer.